# Configure HAProxy ACL using environment variables with multiple IP addresses/networks

Tags: haproxy

I know you can use [environment variables](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.9/configuration.html#2.3) to configure **HAProxy**. It is working for me with a single value.

But, **is it possible to use an environment variable with a list of values?** (e.g: multiple src addresses)

For instance, in my `haproxy.cfg`:

```
...
acl acl_gateway_03 src "${ACL_GATEWAY_03_SRC}"
...
```

`ACL_GATEWAY_04_SRC=172.30.4.0/24`

But if I set a list of values (i.e: `ACL_GATEWAY_04_SRC=172.30.4.0/24 172.30.6/24`) the server does not start and shows this error message:

```
[ALERT] 034/181026 (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:47] : error detected while parsing ACL 'acl_gateway_04' : '172.30.4.0/24 127.0.0.1' is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an acl for each ip range.

```
acl acl_gateway_03 src 172.30.4.0/24
```

or you can write a command in crontab to write the ranges of ips in files and use them in haproxy as below:

```
acl acl_gateway_03 -f file1.lst -i -f file2.lst test
```

> The "-f" flag is followed by the name of a file from which all lines will be read as individual values. It is even possible to pass multiple "-f" arguments if the patterns are to be loaded from multiple files. Empty lines as well as lines beginning with a sharp ('#') will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

As user16818195 said in his [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75254291/21132794), according to [documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#2.3):

If the variable contains a list of several values separated by spaces, like this:

```
ENV_VAR=10.0.0.7 10.0.0.9 10.0.0.11
```

You need to reference the environment variable this way in the haproxy configuration file:

```
acl your_acl src "${ENV_VAR[*]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#2.3), this is supported but I couldn't figure out how exactly to do that:

> If the variable contains a list of several values separated by spaces,
> it can be expanded as individual arguments by enclosing the variable
> with braces and appending the suffix '[*]' before the closing brace.